# SharePoint list events point to old list path

Tags: list, calendar, path

After changing the name of a Calendar and its path , if I create a new event the event still points to the old path.

```
http://mysitecollection/Lists/MyOldListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=57
```

This means that I cannot edit the event because if I click on it I get "`Page not found"`
I changed the calendar name from SharePoint Designer/`All Files/Lists` as suggested in other posts.

Comment: Why do you want to rename it?you can do one thing create calendar list stp with data and make your list from that stp with the name you want!!Let me know if this is not what you want..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which method did you try to change the path, but 3 ways to change the url. Try one of them .

1. Using PowerShell
2. Using SharePoint Designer
3. By Opening the List or Library in Windows Explorer

look at the link:[Click](http://www.netwoven.com/2016/02/3-ways-to-change-the-url-of-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/)